# Как научить  python видеть график

Tags: python

У меня вопрос в общем такой, как научить питон "видеть" картинку (сделанную принт скрином) и снять с этой картинки значения (в нашем случае график).

В интернете ни чего не нашел, а в книгах возможно не заметил как питон "достает" информацию из внешнего мира. По этому прошу подсказать хотя бы пару книг, где четко прописано как работать с внешним миром.

Comment: @timob не ясно, вам нужна информация по тому, как взаимодействовать с ОС или по тому, как распознавать изображение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычное распознавание текста вроде ABBYY FineReader. Задачу могу охарактеризовать как «неосуществимую»… Можете попытаться найти открытые библиотеки OCR или заказать разработку для Вас у крупных игроков рынка, вроде того-же ABBYY (если хватит денег).

Если хотите сделать сами, стоит копать в сторону самообучающихся нейронных сетей…

Answer (score 1):

Можно попиксельно анализировать изображение, параллельно составить определённый словарь сочетаний пикселов. Но это всё замутно, скорее всего вы не правильно ставите себе задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону OpenCV.
Вот [статейка](http://illumium.org/node/58) как распознают светофор на фото.